# Simple PowerBI Dax Problem (Select text value from table)

Tags: powerbi, dax

Dummy example below explaining my issue:

Data:

Methods of travel

| Recency | Method |..... Date ....|
|...1...........|...Car.....|2021-10-01|
|...2...........|..Lorry....|2021-09-01|
|...3...........|..Bike.....|2021-08-01|

I am trying to create a measure which selects the most recent method of travel.

E.g. in SQL:

```
Select method From Table where recency = (select min(recency) from table)
```

Two things i have tried so far:

```
Calculate(max(Table[method])Filter(Table,Table[Recency] = [Min_Recency]))
```

And

```
Lookupvalue(Table[Method],Table[Recency],[Min_Recency])
```

Where [Min_Recency] gives back the min(Recency)

Comment: It will depend on the filter context, what sort of output are you trying to achieve? can you share a tabular output as an example?

Comment: Just need a card that states the method of travel that was most recent.

E.g. If i put in a slicer and filter on dates for a max date of 2021-09-02, then the output in the card will be 'Lorry'.

To get the minimum recency (in my example there are multiple rows with the same date) I used the following:
Min_Recency=
calculate(min(table[recency]),filter(table[date]=max(table[date])))

I feel like i should be able to then say 
Calculate(table[Method]),Filter(table[Recency])=[Min_Recency]

But after 'calculate(' there needs to be a syntax that works.

Answer (score 1):

I have expanded your table to make it easier to explain.

`TABLE`

| Recency | Method | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Car | 2021-10-01 |
| 2 | Lorry | 2021-09-01 |
| 3 | Bike | 2021-09-01 |
| 4 | Bike | 2021-08-01 |

### Calculation: Measure

```
MostRecentMethod =
VAR SelectedDate =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Date] )
VAR MinRecency =
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Table'[Recency] ), 'Table'[Date] = SelectedDate )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Method] ), 'Table'[Recency] = MinRecency )
```

### Output

**Table Visual**

[image]

**Card Visual**

[image]